# как сохранить состояния кнопки при выходе из activity

Tags: android

По нажатию на кнопку нужно чтобы она сохранила свое состояние, и после перезапуска `activity` была в неактивном состоянии.
Записать куда-то состояние кнопки, а при следующем запуске считать. Как этого можно добиться?

Comment: Записать куда-то состояние кнопки. При следующем запуске читать.

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Можно сохранить в [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

```
 final static String BUTTON_PRESSED = "button_pressed";
```

Сохранить при нажатии кнопки

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 sharedPref.edit()
     .putBoolean(BUTTON_PRESSED, true)
     .apply();
```

Получить, например, в `onCreate()`

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 boolean isButtonPressed = sharedPref.getBoolean(BUTTON_PRESSED, false);
```

[подробнее](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=ru)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, Вы использовали для переключения активностей Intent. Возьмите функцию putextra() и положите в нее Boolean, в зависимости от значения которого активность примет тот или иной вид.